# Jest/Enzyme | Failed to parse data-test="basic-render"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have **two render methods** in my React component. Everything depends on what these function returns.

```
  validateUserExists = username =>
    listUsers().then(({ data }) => {
      if (Array.isArray(data) && data.includes(username)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
```

It takes the username from the API, and if it exists in the `listUsers()`, then returns true or false. Based on that the component render either the `NoUser` or `BasicRender`.

**Here is the Test:**

```
  describe('User does not exist', () => {
    let match;
    let validateUserExistsFn;
    let fetchUserFn;
    beforeEach(() => {
      match = { params: { username: 'testUser' }, isExact: true, path: '', url: '' };
      validateUserExistsFn = jest.fn();
      fetchUserFn = jest.fn();
    });

    it('should render NoResource Component when user', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(
        <UserDetailsScreen
          match={match}
          fetchUsers={fetchUserFn}
          validateUserExists={validateUserExistsFn}
        />,
        {
          disableLifecycleMethods: true
        }
      );
      console.log(wrapper.debug());
      const BasicRender = wrapper.find(`[data-test="basic-render]`);
      expect(BasicRender).toHaveLength(1);
    });
```

**Here is the component code:**

```
class UserDetailsScreen extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.shape({
      isExact: PropTypes.bool,
      params: PropTypes.object,
      path: PropTypes.string,
      url: PropTypes.string
    }),
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
    history: PropTypes.object,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    actualValue: PropTypes.string,
    callBack: PropTypes.func
  };

  state = {
    user: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUser();
  }

  getUserUsername = () => {
    const { match } = this.props;
    const { params } = match;
    return params.username;
  };

  fetchUser = () => {
    getUser(this.getUserUsername()).then(username => {
      this.setState({
        user: username.data
      });
    });
  };

  validateUserExists = username =>
    listUsers().then(({ data }) => {
      if (Array.isArray(data) && data.includes(username)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });

  redirectToUsers = () => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
    history.push('/management/users');
  };

  renderNoResourceComponent = () => (
    <div className="center-block" data-test="no-resource-component">
      <NoResource
        icon="exclamation-triangle"
        title="Ooops"
        primaryBtn="Back to Users"
        primaryCallback={this.redirectToUsers}
      >
        <span className="font-weight-bold">404: User does not exist</span>
        <br />
        Please choose from one in the usersLists
      </NoResource>
    </div>
  );

  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;
    const { callBack, actualValue, label } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
          </Fragment>
        ) : (
            <div className="container-fluid">
              {this.renderNoResourceComponent()}
            </div>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(UserDetailsScreen);
```

And here is what the `wrapper.debug()` **returns**, which I have never seen before:

```
      <Route>
        [function children]
      </Route>
```

I found out in the proccess, that i need to wrap my test my `BrowserRouter` from react-router-dom. Which I did and it printed me this on debug:

```
    <Router history={{...}}>
        <UserDetailsScreen match={{...}} fetchUsers={[Function: mockConstructor]} />
        };
      </Router>
```

After that no much luck. i get the same error, over and over again.

I mean for whatever data-test attribute I am going to look, it always returns this. I am at this thing for 5+ hours. Can someone help me solve this? Thanks!!

Comment: At least you're missing a quote in [data-test="basic-render]

Comment: Yeah did that a while ago, sorry, I had the question ready a few hours ago.. Doesn't change the fact, that the thing doesn't get rendered... Just the second thing I posted.. Thanks though..

Comment: It looks like you need to do a [Full DOM Rendering](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) using `mount` instead of using `shallow`